# Too many <chrono> errors (std::chrono::timepoint) (VS2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, std, c++-chrono

In my project, before I upgraded to VS2015, it compiled just fine. Now I'm getting 10 errors that have to do with std::chrono::timepoint.
These are all the errors: https://gyazo.com/0d3c51cf87c49661b0f24da4a027b0d9
(image since there's so many)

Example lines of code that cause errors:

`fStart = clock::now();` causes `no operator '=' matches these operands`

`double t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(clock::now() - fStart).count();`

causes

`no instance of function template 'std::chrono::duraction_cast' matches the argument list. argument types are: ( <error-type> )`

(fStart is a chrono::system_clock::timepoint, t is a double obviously)

Here is the full function those errors are from if someone wants to see it:

```
void Animation::update() {
    using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    if (animType == TYPE_MS) {
        if (firstUpdate) {
            fStart = clock::now();
            firstUpdate = false;
        }

    double t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(clock::now() - fStart).count();

    if (!paused) {
        if (t >= frames[frame]->getTime())
            advance();
    }
} else if (animType == TYPE_FRAME) {
    if (firstUpdate)
        firstUpdate = false;

    if (!paused)
        fTime += speed;

        if (speed < 0.0) {
            if (fTime <= -frames[frame]->getTime())
                advance();
        } else {
            if (fTime >= frames[frame]->getTime())
                advance();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I supposed to do to fix these?

Comment: How are we supposed to know, if you don't tell us what `fStart` is? :)

Comment: In general, a minimal, reproducible example would be immensely helpful.

Comment: `std::chrono::time_point` is a template. time_points from different clocks are not necessarily convertible. We need to know the *actual* type.

Comment: It is defined as `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point fStart;` in the class's header.

Comment: Then that's your problem. You can't store a `high_resolution_clock::time_point` in a `system_clock::time_point`

Comment: Why was it compiling and working as expected before I upgraded from VS2013 to VS2015?

Comment: It comes down to the standard library implementation. The two clocks can happen to be the same clock, but you can't rely on that if the standard doesn't specify it.

Comment: See `[std::chrono::high_resolution_clock] may be an alias of std::chrono::system_clock or std::chrono::steady_clock, or a third, independent clock.` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend abandoning use of `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

If you need a `time_point` that has to be stable across processor runs, or processes, use `std::chrono::system_clock`, which has a definitive relationship to the civil calendar.

Otherwise use `std::chrono::steady_clock`.  This clock is like a stopwatch.  It is good for timing stuff, but it can't tell you the current (civil) time.